# Helicopter crop duster minimum altitude over homes (not field)

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter

I am asking specifically regarding helicopter making approach to  field over home adjacent to field being treated.

In this example:
Helicopter repeatedly passed over my single story rooftop at easily  15-30 meters above rooftop, or less. 
Spray contacting me at same time.

Is this allowed, especially when there appear to be 2-3 other possible alternative approaches that would not require flying over the rooftop of a single family dwelling at such a low altitude?!
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your directions to previously posted information. I am appreciative. I'm truly wanting to understand regulations or generally accepted practices in effort to have a constructive dialog with crop dusting company.     All the best.