# Is it legal for a crop duster to fly right over my house while spraying?

Tags: faa-regulations, aerial-application

A crop duster is flying directly over my house while spraying. I can see the mist coming out while I am standing in the middle of my yard (6 acres). Is this legal?

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39571/helicopter-crop-duster-minimum-altitude-over-homes-not-field https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39448/can-i-stop-crop-dusters-repeatedly-flying-over-my-home

Comment: Is the pilot ACTUALLY SPRAYING CHEMICALS over your house or is he merely flying over your house while working a field?

Comment: People tend to radically over-estimate the angular elevation of an object in the sky. (You can easily verify this by looking up the angular elevation of a star or planet, or the sun or moon, or even the International Space Station, at your location at any given point in time on-line and asking someone else to observe and give their own estimate.) 30 degrees elevation is often perceived to be more like 45, 45 degrees is seen as more like 60, and 60 degrees is perceived to be straight overhead. You are lying flat on your back looking straight up and seeing the aircraft pass directly overhead?

Comment: Over your house, or over the middle of your 6 acre yard?  (Are they your crops?!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. [14 CFR 137.37 - Manner of dispensing](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/137.37) is pretty clear:

> No persons may dispense, or cause to be dispensed, from an aircraft, any material or substance in a manner that creates a hazard to persons or property on the surface.

Flying directly over you or your house *while* spraying is illegal. There are factors like altitude etc, but spraying pesticides over people is rarely legal.

Comment: How do we know the substance being dispersed creates a hazard to person or property?

Comment: @Jonathan Crop dusting usually means spraying pesticides. I've assumed that's what the OP means.

Comment: I think sometimes they spray fertilizer.

Comment: Aerial application can involve many various products, some harmful, some harmless. Some products are completely harmless ("glue" for rapeseed pods), and some merely do not pose a danger in a specific concentration with a specific distribution method. The suggestion that any and all aerial application near or over people is hazardous and illegal is misinformed and perpetuates popular myths that are harmful to the aviation industry.